# Как сделать конструктор простых форм?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Я хочу сделать некий простой конструктор форм, в котором есть возможность создать новую форму, после нажатия на кнопку появляется стандартное окно PyQt5, по нажатию на вторую кнопку можно добавить кнопку в форму, причем ее можно переместить на любое место, после чего можно сохранить данный шаблон в виде готового файла `.exe` или `.py`, а вот как прописать логику взаимодействия кнопок придумать не смог. Если есть идеи как реализовать все выше написанное напишите)

Окно тестовой формы:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'creator.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать окно"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить кнопку"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtdesigner-manual.html

Comment: @S.Nick я понимаю, тут для создание форм используется qt designer, но можно ли сделать что-то подобное в намного более простой форме без него? То есть по факту создать очень сильно упрощенный и урезанный qt designer?

Comment: Settings, мне кажется, что вы замахнулись на очень серьезные вещи. Начните с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1428022

Comment: @S.Nick отлично, это то что нужно, а есть способ хоть как то сохранить результат таких действий в отдельной форме?

Comment: @S.Nick и не могли бы вы немного рассказать про работу кода в том варианте который вы прикрепили?